# How to replace following code with the following changes. Please see the code snippet

Tags: java

I want to change the firstPattern with the secondPattern. When I am using Pattern Matcher / `String.replaceAll()` 
I am using the following logic to replace

```
System.out.println(fileContent.replaceAll(firstPattern, secondPattern));
```

I am getting following error =

```
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3157)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2134)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
```

It is happening because in the first pattern I have used "{" and "}" brace. So it is throwing an error. Don't know how to replace these.

```
    String firstPattern = "text.append(\" where \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\"ObjId\" + \" = \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(getObjId().toString());\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\" and \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\" LastCngDTime =  \");\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        try {\r\n" + 
            "            tempString = dbaExecObj.Get_DataConverter()\r\n" + 
            "                                   .SmsTimeStampToDBMSTimestampString(LastCngDTime,\r\n" + 
            "                    \"-WQ\");\r\n" + 
            "        } catch (Exception e) {\r\n" + 
            "            throw new SmsTntResult(new SmsSystemResult(logger,\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsCsvWhoAmI.getMyFullyQualifiedMethodName(),\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsTntCodes.DATA_TYPE_CONVERSION_ERROR,\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsSystemResult.ERROR));\r\n" + 
            "        }\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(tempString);";
    String secondPattern = "text.append(\" where \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\"ObjId\" + \" = \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(getObjId().toString());\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\" and \");\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\" LastCngDTime =  \");\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        try {\r\n" + 
            "            tempString = dbaExecObj.Get_DataConverter()\r\n" + 
            "                                   .SmsTimeStampToDBMSTimestampString(LastCngDTime,\r\n" + 
            "                    \"-WQ\");\r\n" + 
            "        } catch (Exception e) {\r\n" + 
            "            throw new SmsTntResult(new SmsSystemResult(logger,\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsCsvWhoAmI.getMyFullyQualifiedMethodName(),\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsTntCodes.DATA_TYPE_CONVERSION_ERROR,\r\n" + 
            "                    SmsSystemResult.ERROR));\r\n" + 
            "        }\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "        text.append(\"CAST(\");" +
            "        text.append(tempString);" +
            "        text.append(\" AS datetime)\");";
    String fileContent = new Scanner(new File(filePath)).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    System.out.println(fileContent.replaceAll(firstPattern, secondPattern));
```

Comment: Don't try to parse Java code with regular expressions. Use a proper parser.

Comment: Is there a good reason to be using `replaceAll` here? Would `replace` suffice?

Comment: Escape the { & } with \{ & \}

Comment: replace did my job. Thanks @AndyTurner